# How can I reference an array element when using namespacing backslashes?

Tags: php, namespaces

I am trying to instantiate an object from a class, substituting an element from an array as the classname, but I keep getting PHP parse errors. 
I am thinking the `\` character is somehow escaping the `$` of the array varaiable? 
 i.e.

```
$this->controller = new \app\controllers\$exploded_url[0];
```

gives

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting identifier (T_STRING)

```
$this->controller = new \app\controllers\${exploded_url[0]};
```

gives

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$exploded_url' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

How can I fix this parse error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried:

```
$temp = "\\app\\controllers\\".${exploded_url[0]};
$this->controller = new $temp;
```

Comment: something is off in that syntax if I look at the syntax highlighting

Comment: but did you get idea? you can call new only from string.

Comment: yes, that does work, I thought is might have been possible without using a `$temp` placeholder. Also your closing string is probably going to be escaped by the backslash your syntax should be `"\app\controllers\\"`

Comment: namespaces in strings are just strings, meaning the backslash escapes the quote.